# OZ fluxx Tin Woodman vs the Fighting Trees

Tags: fluxx

The "Tin Woodman" can chop down the "Fighting Trees", now the question is: is this ability played as an action (like playing one card) or a free action, my searches have been unable to find out, is this ability an action or a free action?

Comment: Unless "action" is a thing that was introduced in Oz Fluxx, then it's just something that you can do; like killing a Zombie if you have a card that says you can in Zombie Fluxx. All "actions" are "free actions", you don't have a limited number of "actions" or anything like that in Fluxx.

Comment: I have never played other fluxx games, so I do not have comparability. I was thinking that to activate the text on the Tin Woodman, then I would need to have one play left in order to take down the Fighting Trees, so if I would be out of plays / actions, then I would need to wait my next turn.

Comment: No, plays remaining refers specifically to playing cards; not using abilities of cards you've played.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [The Rules](http://www.looneylabs.com/lit/rules/oz-fluxx-rules):

> Optional actions allowed by new Rules, Keepers, etc., may be performed at any point...

...during the turn sequence. This would include chopping down the Fighting Trees.